# Is there a way to match multiple load impedances with one circuit

Tags: voltage-regulator, load, lm317

My goal is to create a test fixture that can provide multiple voltages such as +-24 volts DC to multiple devices with different input impedances for each device. The ranges of input impedances are large 0-1MΩ+.

I have tried voltage divider circuits which were unsuccessful.

I would like to try a voltage regulator but even with those, I still have to match the impedance to the load circuit via outside resistor voltage divider network, for example, using the LM317. How can I provide one load 5 volts for logic circuits and then unplug that load and plug in a different load to the same line and provide 5 volts to that load (which has a completely different input impedance). I don't think the voltage regulator will allow for that situation will it?

Comment: Is the minimum load impedance really 0 Mohm (i.e. a short circuit)? What is the maximum load current you expect (I assume it is no more than the LM317's 1.5 A limit)?

Comment: It seems like your task is exactly what a voltage regulator is for.  You need to provide 5V, regardless of the connected load.  That's what a voltage regulator does (up to some limit for current.)

Comment: Why do you need to match the impedance? With low frequency power impedance does not typically need to be matched,

Comment: It seems that LM317 is in-between the main circuit and load, therefore no impedance matching is necessary.

Answer (score 6):

> even with [linear reguluators], I still have to match the impedance to the load circuit via outside resistor voltage divider network, for example, using the LM317.

You have a misunderstanding here.

Impedance matching is not required when you want to provide a constant voltage to a load using a linear regulator.

In order to provide a constant voltage, you want the supply circuit (regulator) to present as low as possible an impedance to the load, regardless of what the load impedance is.

If you were thinking that the maximum power transfer theorem requires otherwise, you have misunderstood. The maximum power transfer theorem tells you what load will take the most power from a supply of a given impedance. It doesn't tell you what supply will provide the most power to a given load.

If you thought the control resistors of the LM317 are for impedance matching, that is also not correct. They are used to set the output voltage, they don't affect the regulator circuit's output impedance.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Thank you for correcting me on these. Though, the reason your answer doesn't make sense to me is because I'm picturing the low impedance of the regulator in parallel with the load impedance, similar to a voltage divider. Would the load impedance be in series with the low impedance regulator? Because that would make sense if it was, rather than in parallel, which would destroy the match of the two circuits.